# How can I mass-change the datatype and maxlength of #temp_table columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Consider the following temporary table `#tbl`

```
select * from tempdb.sys.columns where [object_id] = object_id('tempdb..#tbl')

-- results into:

object_id  name    system_type_id  max_length   collation_name
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1          fieldA  231             510          SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
2          fieldB  104               1          NULL
3          fieldC  231             400          SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
4          fieldD  231              -1          SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
5          fieldE  104               1          NULL
.
.
n          fieldF  231             450          SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

I have many columns in `#tbl` and need to mass-change the datatype, maxlength and collation type on all of them so that the end-result is:

```
object_id  name    system_type_id  max_length   collation_name
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1          fieldA  231             510          SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
2          fieldB  231             510          SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
3          fieldC  231             510          SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
4          fieldD  231             510          SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
5          fieldE  231             510          SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
.
.
n          fieldF  231             510          SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

This will then allow me to pivot the columns into rows (which is what my client needs for a report they use in meetings).

Because the number of columns in `#tbl` can be different each time we run the script (and might have different fields) I would like to do this dynamically - in 1 go.

Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: how are you creating these temp tables?

Comment: `select [stuff] into #temp from [db_table1] left join [db_table2];`

Answer (score 0):

Temp tables can be created in 2 way:

**Using `SELECT INTO`:**

```
SELECT Col1, COl2
INTO #temp
FROM [YOUR_TABLE]
```

This method would create `Col1` and `Col2` based on their data type and size in the definition of `[YOUR_TABLE]`, and the Collation would be based on the default of your Database Server. So if you want to change their type/size using this method, you would have to either change the underlying table definition or do some casting of data during the `INSERT`:

```
SELECT CAST(Col1 as nvarchar(max)) as Col1, CAST(Col2 as nvarchar(max)) as Col2
INTO #temp
FROM [YOUR_TABLE]
```

**Using a Table Variable**

The other option is to declare a table variable up front, which gives you some control over column types and sizes:

```
DECLARE @TEMP TABLE (Col1 nvarchar(max), Col2 nvarchar(max))

INSERT INTO @TEMP
SELECT Col1, Col2
FROM [YOUR_TABLE]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
ALTER TABLE #tbl ALTER COLUMN fieldA VARCHAR(510) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Just do this once for each field.